# Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'String' in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that gets a file from a server and parsed the file, I'm using a function with a completion handler like below to get the file

```
func getMachineDetails(completionHandler: @escaping ([MachineDetails]? , Error?) -> Void) {
    var details = [MachineDetails]()
    let url = URL(string: "https://somefile.txt")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { (urlOrnil, responseOrNil, errorOrNil) in
        guard let fileURL = urlOrnil else { return }
        do {
            guard let contents = try? String(contentsOf: fileURL) else { throw errorOrNil! }
            let lines = contents.split(separator: "\n")
            for line in lines {
                let entries = line.split(separator: ";").map { String($0) }
                if entries.count == 4 {
                    let newMachine = MachineDetails(machineNumber:entries[0],
                                                    machineName:entries[1],
                                                    machineXML:entries[2],
                                                    machineWiFi:entries[3])
                    details.append(newMachine)
                } else {
                    print("Malformed line \(line)")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("file error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    print(details)
    completionHandler(details, nil)
}
```

however when I try to use the function

```
func getMachineName(machineNumber: String) -> String {
    getMachineDetails { (machineDetails, error) in
        if let machineDetails = machineDetails {
            let index = machineDetails.firstIndex { $0.machineNumber == machineNumber }
            return machineDetails[index].machineName
        }
    }
}
```

I get the Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'String' error.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The line `completionHandler(details, nil)` must be **inside** the closure (before the `}` above the line. And `getMachineName` cannot have a return value (this causes the error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return in a closure, you are not returning the function `getMachineName`, you are returning the closure itself. Note that the closure is defined to have type `([MachineDetails]? , Error?) -> Void`, meaning once it is called, you won't be returning in the closure. Typically, when you use a closure in a function, and you want to get a value out of that function, the function has a closure as well. You could reformat the function like so:

```
func getMachineName(machineNumber: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        getMachineDetails { (machineDetails, error) in
            if let machineDetails = machineDetails {
                let index = machineDetails.firstIndex { $0.machineNumber == machineNumber }
                completion(machineDetails[index].machineName)
            }
        }
    }
```